# Can an Android app change the settings of the phone such as sound on/off wi-fi on/off?

Tags: android, nfc

Can an Android app change the settings of the phone such as sound on/off or wi-fi on/off? Actually, there will be some predefined NFC tags, and when I tap one of these, let's say, wi-fi will be turned on, or the sound will be turned off? Is that possible with an app?

Comment: Here's one answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863509/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-wifi-on-android-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to mute the phone with programtically, however to change the WiFi on/off, you need to send the user to settings screen for them to do it manually

Here is a link to mute your phone - [Android mute/unmute phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317974/android-mute-unmute-phone)

And here is the code to send the used to settings

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

Taken from [Android: Changing NFC settings (on/off) programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945100/android-changing-nfc-settings-on-off-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I would start here in the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html). This will get you started then take you to the different settings you want to manipulate

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible:

```
public static void setSilent(Context ctx)
{
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT); 
}

public static void setNormal(Context ctx)
{
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL); 
}
```

And for wifi you can use WifiManager:

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

Note that you need a permission for this: android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

NFC Task Launcher is an app that does exactly what you're describing:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher