# Android Studio Mute/Unmute Phone

Tags: android, volume, mute

So this link helps a lot: [Android mute/unmute phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317974/android-mute-unmute-phone)
But I am a not the best at interpreting other people's code and everytime I try to put in there code my program crashes. Could someone help me with how to I can fix it? Spent about an hour trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is in your AndroidManifest.xml add the permission for vibration.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

After that in your activity whenever you want to change it to vibrate use this code (button press etc.)

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

To unmute simply use the code

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Comment: My Code:


*Button 'android:onClick"ClickMe" ||||

MainActivity below the onCreate i have:
public void ClickMe(Context context) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
    } ||

App crashes every time the button is exicuted

Comment: I cannot see what you are doing there.  What should be happening is defining your button (Button mute = findViewById(R.id.yourbutton)

Then you should create an onClick event and put the code in there like button.setOnClickListener etc.

Comment: Thanks, still learning the Android Development Kit. Problem Solved!

Comment: Glad to help!  Ask if you need help.