# How to mute a phone ringing on incoming call

Tags: android, audio, ringtone, incoming-call

How can I mute Android phone ringing at an incoming call programmatically? (Like doing this by pressing power button at incoming call)?

I know about `setStreamMute` and `adjustStreamVolume`, but I think there is a better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rejecting Incoming call in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012082/rejecting-incoming-call-in-android)

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012082/rejecting-incoming-call-in-android

Comment: Do you mean to mute the ringing audio but keep the phone ringing silently?

Comment: @AhmadAghazadeh it is not duplicate, i don't want to reject a call.

Comment: @Stefan, yes, I mean it.

Comment: I think you can find some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801646/android-studio-mute-unmute-phone-help there seems to be a `setRingerMode` perhaps that will help you.

Answer (score 4):

`setStreamMute()` is deprecated in and above Build version 23 (marshmallow). You can use `adjustStreamVolume()` for marshmallow and above.

```
public void adjustAudio(boolean setMute) {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int adJustMute;
        if (setMute) {
            adJustMute = AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE;
        } else {
            adJustMute = AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE;
        }
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, adJustMute, 0);
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, adJustMute, 0);
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, adJustMute, 0);
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, adJustMute, 0);
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, adJustMute, 0);
    } else {
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, setMute);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, setMute);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, setMute);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, setMute);
        audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, setMute);
    }
}
```

You can call this method like,

```
adjustAudio(true) // To mute all the system, ringer, alarm, music, notification sounds on any event like button click.

adjustAudio(false) // To unmute all the system, ringer, alarm, music, notification sounds on any event like button click.
```

Comment: Very Nice.. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, I have a query. How to mute my call? I tried with AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL but it didn't work. Kindly help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.